# Unique_ptr of unique_ptr in decorator pattern

Tags: c++11, nested, unique-ptr

Given a decorator class with standard decorator CTOR

```
explicit TheDecorator(std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> &&p_rrBase);
```

I want to create a member variable that is a unique ptr of such a decorator. I thus tried

```
unique_ptr<DerivedClass> spToDeco(make_unique<DerivedClass>() ); // class to decorate
m_spDecoration = make_unique<TheDecorator>( move(spToDeco) ); // unique ptr of decorator
```

Using VS 2010 and Scott Meyers implentation of make_unique (without variadic templates, implementing both a version with zero and one argument(s) instead), I get the error

```
error C2780: _Ty &&std::forward(...): expects 1 argument -- 0 provided
```

which I understand, as "TheDecorator" expects the argument to forward. But where the heck do I have to code it into, how do I form the syntax correctly? Am I supposed to include a move in the  <> brackets? Thanks a lot for help!

---

Make_Unique:

```
namespace std
{
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T() );
}

template<typename T, typename Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&& params)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(std::forward<Ts>()) );
}
}
```

---

EDIT 2: SOLVED already, it must read

```
    template<typename T, typename Ts>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&& params)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(std::forward<Ts>(params)) );
}
```

Comment: include that implementation of `make_unique`

Comment: Edit: includes make_unique implementation

Comment: ARGH, thanks already! I forgot to insert "params".

Comment: in the long run, it's UB to add anything to the `std` namespace on your own

Comment: Yep, that's right. This is just done as we switch to VS 2015 soon, which makes the file redundant and makes the code not need any further change. It is an exception...